# Hive HCatalog - Retrieve Table Metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I have been using Hive Hcatalog API's to retrieve table/column metadata.

Code Sample :

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
HCatClient client = HCatClient.create(configuration);
HCatTable hCatTable = client.getTable("schemaName", "tableName");
```

Using `hCatTable` instance am able to retrieve columns `hCatTable.getCols()`, partition columns `hCatTable.getPartCols()` etc.. which returns list of `HCatFieldSchema`

The problem is that am not able to retrieve column length, scale, precision from  `HCatFieldSchema` instance.

Is there any way to get the above column metadata using Hive Hcatalog API's?

> Hive version used : 1.1.0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of using HCat API, you can use the hive metastore which is generally stored in RDBMS.